# Showing file directory on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, title, directory

I'm just starting to learn how to use Sharepoint. I don't have a background in IT and am not very sure of the correct terms to use to use so do please bear with me as I try to explain.

I understand that SharePoint uses the root folder name as part of the url. After creation of the root folder, we can change SharePoint library title where by doing so, does not change its internal name (which is the root folder name).

In my SharePoint site, I have a few document libraries which have been assigned internal names and I renamed the title for each one of them. I'd like to facilitate navigation on Sharepoint by showing the directory.  Is it possible to display on Sharepoint, a directory that is in some form of Tree/branching format, but reflect the  title of the document library, instead of the root folder name?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint navigation, we have a feature called tree view which will display the site contents in a hierarchy like this. And it uses the title instead of the internal name. Please check this [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_mac-mso_o365b/sharepoint-why-no-tree-view/40d61977-30a2-4648-985c-cf944beeec42) for the detailed steps.

[image]

However it only works for SharePoint classic experience. So you may need to check your SharePoint Version. This [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/which-version-of-sharepoint-am-i-using-3575ff57-037f-48cf-9398-99080c34b25f) shall be helpful. For now, only SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2019 has modern experience. If you are not using them, then you have no need to worry about it. If you are using them, a bit [information about the two experience](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f) will be helpful.

And you can [switch back to classic experience in default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-and-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9) when you need. And you can find `return to classic experience` link on left bottom.

[image]